# Create a query based on multiple tables by foreign id

Tags: mysql, node.js

i have two tables

the first one for `user`

```
+----------------------------------------
| ID | name                 | age       |
+----------------------------------------
| 1  | name 1               | 24         |
| 2  | name 2               | 20         |
| 4  | name 3               | 18         |
| 5  | name 4               | 30         |
----------------------------------------+
```

second one for `user images` with foreign key

```
+---------------------------------------+
| ID | imageurl_id          | image     |
+---------------------------------------+
| 1  | 1                    | pic 1.jpg |
| 2  | 2                    | pic 2.jpg |
| 3  | 2                    | pic 3.jpg |
| 4  | 4                    | pic 4.jpg |
| 5  | 4                    | pic 5.jpg |
| 6  | 4                    | pic 6.jpg |
+---------------------------------------+
```

some users have more than one image and some have no image.

I use Nodejs API.

I want to collect this tow table by SQL query with out Repetition like this.

```
{
 "info":[ 
  {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "name 1",
  "age": 24,
  },
  ]
 "image": [
    {
   "imageurl_id": 1,
   "image": "pic 1.jpg "
    }
  ]
 "info":[ 
  {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "name 2",
  "age": 20,

  },
  ]
 "image": [
    {
   "imageurl_id": 2,
   "image": "pic 2.jpg "
    }
    {
   "imageurl_id": 2,
   "image": " pic 3.jpg "
    }
  ]
}
```

and when is there no images for the user it give me empty image [].

Comment: For name 2 id will be 2 ...right ? where are you facing the issue ?

Comment: The issue is how can i collect this two tables to get the las result ?